# Can't get statistics using Analytics v4 on android

Tags: android, google-analytics

I'm trying to use analytics on my app, I'm still on develompent so the app hasn't been published yet but as far as I know I should see statistics anyways.
I've used the following tutorial: http://java.dzone.com/articles/working-google-analytics-api
And everything works fine until I get this message on LogCat:

```
10-07 17:13:08.700: V/GAV4(21437): Thread[main,5,main]: Connected to service
10-07 17:13:08.705: V/GAV4(21437): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Initialized GA Thread
10-07 17:13:08.730: V/GAV4(21437): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Loaded clientId
10-07 17:13:08.735: V/GAV4(21437): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Storing hashed adid.
10-07 17:13:08.735: V/GAV4(21437): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Loaded clientId
10-07 17:13:08.735: V/GAV4(21437): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: putHit called
10-07 17:13:08.735: V/GAV4(21437): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Sending hit to service   PATH: https:  PARAMS: ul=it-it,  ht=1412694783750,  sr=480x800,  a=289400925,  sc=start,  sf=100.0,  aid=*,  cid=*,  av=1.3,  v=1,  t=screenview,  an=*,  tid=*,  _u=.2nKK8,  cd=com.*.*.MainActivity,
```

The app doesn't send the Hit to the service. Can anyone explain how to fix this?
(I covered the info of my app with * but they're correct)